# Error con localtime_s que impide obtener la hora local del sistema

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Estoy intentando compilar y ejecutar el siguiente código en Dev C++:

```
//Diseño de Pantalla
#include <stdio.h> // Biblioteca estándar de entrada/salida. Si quieres usar printf y scanf
#include <stdlib.h>/* la librería stdlib.h es necesaria para que "system" funcione */
#include <windows.h> // para el system y Sleep
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>
/* conio.h   no es una librería estándar, sólo los compiladores de Borland pueden usarla.
 background(), clrscr(), gotoxy(a,b), getch(), textcolor(), cprintf() */
#include <time.h> //Libreria que contiene las funciones de tiempo del sistema. 
 
/***Declaracion de Variables****/                

int dia,mes,anio,Hor,Min,Sec; 
int hor, ver;

//PROCEDIMIENTO OBTENER LA FECHA Y HORA DEL SISTEMA
void fec() 
{

 time_t current_time;
 struct tm local_time;
 time ( &current_time );
 localtime_s(&local_time, &current_time);
  anio = local_time.tm_year + 1900; // Años transcurridos desde 1900
  mes = local_time.tm_mon + 1; // Número del mes (0-11)
  dia = local_time.tm_mday; // Día del mes (1-31)
  Hor = local_time.tm_hour; // Horas desde medianoche (0-23)
  Min = local_time.tm_min; // Minutos pasados de la hora (0-59)
  Sec = local_time.tm_sec;// Segundos pasados del minuto (0-61)

  }

//PROCEDIMIENTO MOSTRAR UNA PANTALLA

void portada()
{
    
//Declaracion de Cabecera para utilizar el posicionamiento
HANDLE hConsoleOutput;
COORD coord;
hConsoleOutput = GetStdHandle (STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);   

//int hor, ver;
 char clave[10];
 char nombre[30];
ver=3;
 system ("cls");
    system("color 10");
/*x es para la posicion en horizontal y Y para el vertical*/
coord.X = 50; coord.Y = ver;
SetConsoleCursorPosition (hConsoleOutput, coord);

//fec();
    printf( "Caracas, %3i / %3i /  %5i",dia,mes,anio );

ver=ver+2;
/*x es para la posicion en horizontal y Y para el vertical*/
coord.X =10;  coord.Y = ver;
SetConsoleCursorPosition (hConsoleOutput, coord);
    printf( " ************  TRABAJO *********** " );

ver=ver+20;
coord.X = 40; coord.Y = ver;
SetConsoleCursorPosition (hConsoleOutput, coord);
    printf( "Nombre :");

ver=ver+3;

ver=ver+18; 
coord.X = 10; coord.Y = ver;
SetConsoleCursorPosition (hConsoleOutput, coord);   
//fec();
    printf( "HORA:, %3i : %3i ", Hor, Min);
ver=ver+2;  
coord.X = 10; coord.Y = ver;
SetConsoleCursorPosition (hConsoleOutput, coord);   

system("pause");    
    
}
//PROCEDIMIENTO MOSTRAR UN MENSAJE
void Mensaje()
{

//Declaracion de Cabecera para utilizar el posicionamiento
HANDLE hConsoleOutput;
COORD coord;
hConsoleOutput = GetStdHandle (STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);   
            system ("cls"); 
    ver=3;
    system("color 50");
    coord.X = 40; coord.Y = ver;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition (hConsoleOutput, coord); 
   // fec();
    printf( "Caracas, %3i / %3i /  %5i",dia,mes,anio );

    ver=ver+20;
   coord.X = 20; coord.Y = ver;
   SetConsoleCursorPosition (hConsoleOutput, coord); 

    printf("Bienvenido al  Sistema   ");
    ver=ver+22;
   coord.X = 40; coord.Y = ver;
   SetConsoleCursorPosition (hConsoleOutput, coord);
    system("pause");

             }
 /* PROGRAMA    INGRESA 2 NÚMEROS, MUESTRA  LA  SUMAS DE ELLOS  */

void Suma()
{
//Declaracion de Cabecera para utilizar el posicionamiento
HANDLE hConsoleOutput;
COORD coord;
hConsoleOutput = GetStdHandle (STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

/***Declaracion de Variables****/  
int A, B,R; // valor 1 , valor 2 , Resultado

 system ("cls");
 system("color 40");
 ver=3;
    /*x es para la posicion en horizontal y Y para el vertical*/
    coord.X = 30; coord.Y = ver;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition (hConsoleOutput, coord);
 //   fec();
    printf( "Caracas, %3i / %3i /  %5i",dia,mes,anio );
    ver=ver+2;
    coord.X = 20; coord.Y = ver;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition (hConsoleOutput, coord);
    printf(" ***************   Suma    ***************      ");
    
    ver=ver+5;
coord.X = 20; coord.Y = ver;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition (hConsoleOutput, coord);   
printf( " Introduce números 1: " );
scanf ("%i", &A);
    ver=ver+2;
coord.X = 22; coord.Y = ver;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition (hConsoleOutput, coord);
printf(" Introduce números 2: " );
scanf ( "%i",&B);
R=A+B;
    ver=ver+2;
coord.X = 24; coord.Y = ver;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition (hConsoleOutput, coord);
printf(" Suma de números   %i",R );
ver=ver+2;  
coord.X = 10; coord.Y = ver;
SetConsoleCursorPosition (hConsoleOutput, coord);   
system("pause");
}

 /*  *********** Menu   ******************/           
main()
{

//Declaracion de Cabecera para utilizar el posicionamiento
HANDLE hConsoleOutput;
COORD coord;
hConsoleOutput = GetStdHandle (STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);   

    int opc,s;// seleccion de las opciones
    s=1;
        portada();

    while(s<=5){

 system ("cls");
 system("color 60");
 ver=3;
    /*x es para la posicion en horizontal y Y para el vertical*/

    coord.X = 50; coord.Y = ver;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition (hConsoleOutput, coord);
//    fec();
    printf( "Caracas, %3i / %3i /  %5i",dia,mes,anio );

    ver=ver+2;
    coord.X = 10; coord.Y = ver;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition (hConsoleOutput, coord);

    printf (" *********** Menu de Opciones *****************");  
    ver=ver+2;
    coord.X = 20; coord.Y = ver;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition (hConsoleOutput, coord);
    printf(" Mensaje       Opci\340n 1\n");
    ver=ver+2;
    coord.X = 20; coord.Y = ver;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition (hConsoleOutput, coord);
    printf(" Suma          Opci\340n 2\n");
    ver=ver+2;
    coord.X = 20; coord.Y = ver;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition (hConsoleOutput, coord);
    printf(" Salir         Opci\340n 3\n");  
        ver=ver+3;
    coord.X = 10; coord.Y = ver;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition (hConsoleOutput, coord);

     printf("   Teclear una opci\340n:  ");
        scanf("%i",&opc);
        switch(opc)
        {
            case 1:
                ver=ver+2;
                coord.X = 20; coord.Y = ver;
                SetConsoleCursorPosition (hConsoleOutput, coord);
                printf("Opcion 1 seleccionada");
               Mensaje();
                break;
            case 2:
                ver=ver+2;
                coord.X = 20; coord.Y = ver;
                SetConsoleCursorPosition (hConsoleOutput, coord);
                printf("Opcion 2 seleccionada");
                Suma();

                break;
            case 3:
                ver=ver+2;
                coord.X = 20; coord.Y = ver;
                SetConsoleCursorPosition (hConsoleOutput, coord);
                printf("Opcion 3 seleccionada");
                ver=ver+2;
                coord.X = 20; coord.Y = ver;
                SetConsoleCursorPosition (hConsoleOutput, coord);
                printf("Salir \n\n");
                ver=ver+2;
                coord.X = 20; coord.Y = ver;
                SetConsoleCursorPosition (hConsoleOutput, coord);
                printf(" Fin de Proceso ");
                ver=ver+20;
                coord.X = 20; coord.Y = ver;
                SetConsoleCursorPosition (hConsoleOutput, coord);
               system("pause");
               return 0;
                break;

            default:
            ver=ver+2;
            coord.X = 20; coord.Y = ver;
            SetConsoleCursorPosition (hConsoleOutput, coord);
                printf("Opcion no disponible");
                ver=ver+2;
                coord.X = 20; coord.Y = ver;
                SetConsoleCursorPosition (hConsoleOutput, coord);
                system("pause");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

**Y me da el siguiente error:**

```
localtime_s(&local_time, &current_time); //esta es la línea que da el **error: 'localtime_s' was not declared in this scope**
```

He googleado y buscado en un montón de sitios, pero no he dado con la solución. Estuve revisando la librería time.h en su carpeta del programa en la computadora para ver si conseguía alguna referencia, puesto que en google el error muestra una variedad de códigos que no se parecen a este ejemplo. Y entonces conseguí esta librería en la ubicación [\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include] y noté que allí aparecía declarado  'localtime_r', por lo que intenté cambiar la "s" por la "r", pero el error se repite.

Luego intenté

```
localtime(&local_time, &current_time);
```

Con el error:

```
cannot convert 'tm*' to 'const time_t* {aka const long int*}' for argument '1' to 'tm* localtime(const time_t*)'
```

Por eso vengo aquí a solicitar alguna ayuda u orientación que haga que funcione sin errores.

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Parece que esa función es sólo para el compilador de Microsoft.

Una solución puede ser:

```
void fec()
{
    time_t current_time;
    struct tm *local_time;
    time ( &current_time );
#if _MSC_VER
    localtime_s(localTM, localTime);
    anio = local_time.tm_year + 1900; // Años transcurridos desde 1900
    mes = local_time.tm_mon + 1; // Número del mes (0-11)
    dia = local_time.tm_mday; // Día del mes (1-31)
    Hor = local_time.tm_hour; // Horas desde medianoche (0-23)
    Min = local_time.tm_min; // Minutos pasados de la hora (0-59)
    Sec = local_time.tm_sec;// Segundos pasados del minuto (0-61)
#else
    local_time = localtime(&current_time);
    anio = 1900 + local_time->tm_year;
    mes = 1 + local_time->tm_mon;
    dia = local_time->tm_mday;
    Hor = local_time->tm_hour;
    Min = local_time->tm_min;
    Sec = local_time->tm_sec;
#endif
}
```

struct tm : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/tm/

De esta forma, sólo si compilas con Visual C++ se ejecutará haciendo uso de `localtime_s`

Comment: Efectivamente esa respuesta fue correcta, muchisimas gracias

Comment: Ahora sí compila y ejecuta, pero me doy cuenta que no está tomando la hora del sistema, me asigna 0 a todos los valores de hora, minutos, segundos y fecha. No estoy usando Visual C++ sino el del entorno DOS con DEV C++.

Comment: Disculpa, la respuesta estaba incompleta porque no añadí las variables Hor, Min y Sec. Ya están puestas, además de un enlace al struct tm por si quieres profundizar sobre sus miembros